# JavaFX DoubleProperty intValue() method returns always 0 where is to return 0....100

Tags: java, javafx, properties, numbers

> Description

I have a `Label` with it's text binded to a `ProgressBar` progressProperty. Then i multiply the value of the progress bar with 100 , and **i want the bar to show that value of the progress bar * 100 as integer plus %** , for example `"50 %"` or `"25 %"` etc:

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(progressBar.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).intValue()," %");
```

> The problem

The `.intValue()` method always returns 0 for some reason . If i remove it returns the value of the progress bar which is double , example `25,05345 %` , `32,3456534 %`...

> Finally

Why `intValue()` acts like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have answered your question but anyway...

Firstly, your sample code has one missing `)`, and I'm going to assume it is actually there (or else it won't compile), and it's at the end.

Secondly, `Bindings.concat()` takes in any objects, not just observables. So `Bindings.concat(new Object(), new Object());` would compile fine, but wouldn't be useful. In your case, you are calling this method as `Bindings.concat(int, String)` with the `int` autoboxed into `Integer`.

From [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#concat-java.lang.Object...-):

> If one of the arguments implements ObservableValue and the value of
>   this ObservableValue changes, the change is automatically reflected in
>   the StringExpression.

Since you did not give the method any observable, you are going to get the value of your binding expression at the time the method is run, which happens to be `0`.

You can do this:

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%1$.0f %%", progressBar.progressProperty().multiply(100.00)));
```

Or use what you already came up with via `Bindings.createStringBinding()`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i am missing something or the below binding is being carbage collected ?

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(progressBar.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).intValue()," %");
```

So i replaced with the below and it works ...

```
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> String.format("Work Done : %d %%", progressBar.progressProperty().multiply(100.00).intValue()),
        progressBar.progressProperty()));
```